# How to trap "blur" or "keypress" enter 13 in javascript jquery - OR not, both

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

I want to capture "enter" and "blur" on a form field.  If I hit "enter" and "tab", it will also trigger the blur event...  Only one trigger, so "OR" not "AND.

```
$('#login-input-password').bind('blur keypress', function(e){
         if (e.type == 'blur' || e.keyCode == 13) {
            // do something only once, not twice
            // e.g., if I hit "[enter"] and tab to blur, I don't want it to call twice...
         }
    });
```

#### answer accepted implemented

FUNCTION usage

```
function bindTriggerEnterOrBlur(selector,myFunction)
    {
    $(selector).bind('blur keypress', function(e){
        if (e.type == 'blur' || e.keyCode == 13) {
            if (!$(selector).data('has-triggered')) {
                    $(selector).data('has-triggered', true);
                 // do something only once, not twice
                 myFunction();
                // e.g., if I hit "[enter"] and tab to blur, I don't want it to call twice...
                }
             }
        });

    $(selector).bind('focus', function(e){
            $(selector).data('has-triggered', false);
            $(selector).select();   
        });
    }
```

CALL to FUNCTION

```
bindTriggerEnterOrBlur('#login-input-email',submitLoginEmail);
```

Where submitLoginEmail is the function that does something for the trigger, e.g.,

```
function submitLoginEmail()
    {
    // submit on enter...
    var email = $("#login-input-email").val();
    if(validEmail(email))   
        {  
        submitNextLogin(); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not have two event handlers. They are not related at all

Comment: You want a XOR operator in your if, but it isn't really going to do anything. You're still going to call the handler for both events if they happen at the same time as they will be fired separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am getting your requirement right, you want to execute the callback only once but currently it is getting executed twice.

If that is the case then you will need some way to indicate if the callback has been called already.

One way would be to use data attributes

```
$('#login-input-password').bind('blur keypress', function(e){
     if (e.type == 'blur' || e.keyCode == 13) {
        if (!$(this).data('done') {
            $(this).data('done', true);
         // do something only once, not twice
        // e.g., if I hit "[enter"] and tab to blur, I don't want it to call twice...
        }
     }
});
```

You will also need another event handler to reset the done attribute of the element

```
$('#login-input-password').bind('focus', function(e) {
    $(this).data('done', false);
});
```

Comment: This seems reasonable, can it be wrapped into a generic fn "blurEnter" ... possibly changing 'done' to "has-triggered" in the data attribute.

Comment: When and how do you "reset" back to "false"?

Comment: the second piece of code, the callback for `focus` resets the status to false whenever cursor enters your input password element.

Comment: Nice work, I updated my question to demonstrate an abstracted form of your answer with a generic function call.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an OR. You want a XOR (Exclusive OR), which has to be done using a combination of comparisons.

```
if (( (e.type == 'blur') && !(e.keyCode == 13)) || 
    (!(e.type == 'blur') &&  (e.keyCode == 13))) {
  // do something only once, not twice
  // e.g., if I hit "[enter"] and tab to blur, I don't want it to call twice...
}
```

You want to prevent the script from firing again though, so you'll need to do even more state comparison to make sure your asynchronous event handler knows that the `blur` or `keypress` events have occurred and ensure the handler doesn't run twice.

Comment: Yes, to the XOR clarification.  I am not seeing the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like:

```
var doo = function(e){ console.log("do..."); }

$('#wmd-input').bind('blur', doo);
$('#wmd-input').bind('keypress focus', function(e) {
      $('#wmd-input').off('blur');
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        doo(e);
    } else
        $('#wmd-input').bind('blur', doo);
});
```

And it does bind again when focus happens.